# Unable to find read and write items and lists in all site collections permission in Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, postman, webhooks

I am working on Webhook for SharePoint notification using the [Get started with SharePoint webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks#add-webhook-subscription). I have registered the application as a Web Application and tried to provide **read and write items and lists in all site collections** permission. I have checked both delegated and application permissions but i am not able to find these permission.

[Delegate permission screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wlxg.png)

[Application permission screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SZAw.png)

I have followed all the steps except step 1. Can someone tell me how to provide this permission?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided, you are using Authorization Code flow as the grant type.

So you need to add **Delegate permission** rather than **Application permission**.

And what you need to add is `AllSites.Manage` under **SharePoint** (**NOT Microsoft Graph**).

[image]